# PostgreSQL: foreign table with comments

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

When [creating a foreign table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createforeigntable.html) in PostgreSQL 9.6, comments (`COMMENT ON smth IS "Text."`) are not copied from the source `table`/`view` to the destination `foreign table`.

How do I import the comments, without processing every table by hand?